# May I implement a Windows Explorer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I need to implement a Windows explorer with JavaScript. I run the HTML file as HTML Applications (HTAs), so I can run it as normal exe file. I run it in my local file system and manage local file with no server side involved.

The functions I need:

1. User can view all files under a folder
   relative to the HTA file.
2. User can expand and collapse folders.
3. User can click a file to open it, for example, let word open a doc
   file.

May I implement it with JavaScript? Is there any library can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the technical details of HTAs, but if they run the JavaScript using Microsoft's JScript, and if they do so without the usual browser-based security, you could use the various objects available to Windows Scripting Host, including (most notably) the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) in order to enumerate the files and directories.

The rest is just straight-forward DOM manipulation, and if you're allowed to use jQuery in the HTA (you have the `jquery` tag on your question), there are plenty of treeview plug-ins for it, such as [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/).

Comment: Yup, HTAs run without the browser's security restrictions and can use all of the WSH functionality (which is either a terrible gaping security hole, or an awesomely powerful feature, depending on your POV).